# Using IPostBackEventHandler on a Masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, master-pages

I've used `IPostBackEventHandler` on pages in the past for calling the `RaisePostBackEvent` in my code behind via `javascript`.

I'm currently working on a project that requires the same functionality but would be pretty cool if I could put it in my `MasterPage`, I've tried similarly it identically but I'm having no luck, I wonder if someone could point me in the rite direction.

`MasterPage` Declaration :

```
public partial class Master_Pages_MainMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage, IPostBackEventHandler
{
   public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

My Javascript :

```
function myFunction{
  var pageId = '<%= Page.ClientID %>';

  __doPostBack(pageId, 'savePageContent');
}
```

My test page :

```
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

}
```

I've tried adding `IPostBackEventHandler` to TestPage also, unfortunately no luck.

Can anyone help me out or am I being ignorant towards the fact that this isn't achievable using a `MasterPage`?

Regards

P.S. I know I can do this (in my TestPage) :

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
   Master_Pages_MainMasterPage myMaster = (Master_Pages_MainMasterPage)this.Master;

   myMaster.RaisePostBackEvent(eventArgument);
}
```

It's something I don't really want to do on each and every page that uses that `MasterPage`.

Also, ignore the variable naming, I've just made them up for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think it's a very good idea to implement the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface in your master page, because `RaisePostBackEvent` will almost always be page-specific, relating to controls or events on the page.

`System.Web.UI.Page` already implements the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface by default, so you don't need to implement it on every page - it's already there.

You can override the `RaisePostBackEvent` method on the page like this:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the RaisePostBack event 
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == SomeControl)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```